# XNA/MonoGame creating a player

Tags: c#, xna, textures, monogame

After some fine-tuning on my game's GUI I am finally ready to begin with the gameplay. But that's a tall order. My game will be something like a 2D platformer with RPG elements like collecting armor, helmets, weapons etc. So with that in mind I begun thinking about a way to create my player. First, I thought a single `Player` class would do the job for me but since I want to equip the armor/helmet I've acquired, I quickly abandoned this concept.

Next I got another idea. I could have the player's `Head`, `Arms` and `Legs` to be different classes and each of them drawing its own texture, respectively. So I can swap between different armor/helmet sprites for each of the body parts. But that would seem pretty complex to implement... or not?

Could I have a code example on how you would do this? Which path you would take if you are in my stead? Single `Player` class or different body parts classes? If the latter, how would you hook them so that it all looks like a single sprite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would use a single `Player` class element, for simplicities sake. Here I would just have drawing code that accounts for the various upgrades that the player purchases.

For example, I would have some kind of `UpgradeManager` class that holds all the upgrades in a list, based on some `List<Upgrade>` where each upgrade has a `Texture2D` property. Then I would assign the upgrades in a `List<Upgrade>` as a property with the `Player`.

Hopefully this will get you on the right track.

Comment: Sounds alright, but how would you assign the different upgrades to the player?

Comment: I imagine I would have something like an `abstract Equipment` class and have armor/leggings/helmets classes inherit from it, but how would I assign that to the player?

Comment: Like I said, you could use a `List<Equipment>` for equipment assigned to the player, or you could have individual fields for each type of upgrade (armor, weapons, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I would do both. 
I would make separate arms, legs, body, and head classes and keep track of them all within a player class. This way, in your Game1 class and other classes, the player is treated as ine object, but within the class, the body parts are treated separately. 
Hope this helps!